# Floating tiled shower wall and a Schluter type edge

Tags: shower, tile, tiling

To make our walls perfectly flush, our shower wall needs to be floated but the tile we want to use doesn't have a bullnosed version.
As such, we were looking at Schluter type edges. If my tile is 1/4" and my set also 1/4", can I just pick up a 1/2" Schluter type edge and have it envelope the tile and the set so it is flush against the wall?

Comment: What's a "set"?

Comment: I thought that meant like thin set mortar. I think I’m out of my depth...

Comment: No, you're probably fine. Terms vary with region. (And I'm not a tile pro.)

Comment: Can you please expound on what you mean when you say "walls perfectly flush"? Flush with what? I am experienced with floating walls and floors, and tile, but I need a better idea of why you need to float. Your tile will *not* be "flush" if you are using a Schluter edge. How bout a pic?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your mortar probably won't be 1/4" once you press in the tile. If you're careful it'll be not much thicker than the flange on the edge molding, so you generally purchase an edge with a depth matching your tile's thickness.